# Sculpting faces for Animation

Tags: animation, armature, sculpting

I hope these types of questions are welcome here.

I have around 2K - 3K hours in Blender and I've only just started to use the sculpting tool. I heard it has been improved.

I've done some decent models so far but I have a question about sculpting a face for Animation. I have the eye balls and the eye lids as their own separate objects. This is, as far as I know, the way to do it. But when it comes to the mouth I'm a little lost.

Should the model be sculpted with their mouth wide open? So the mouth is made with the lips and then sculpting back to create the inside of the mouth and the back of the throat. Then add the teeth as a separate object?

This is the way I see it being done or I'm totally wrong.

Comment: Usually after sculpting everything needs to be remeshed, because it's really hard to make the sculpt mesh to behave correctly in animation. So the sculpt is not actually a part of finished model. Look at this workflow https://youtu.be/YKMrF0HL2io

Comment: As Filip says, once sculpted you need to retopologize. For the mouth you should keep it neutral and slightly open

Comment: Thank you, good to see I was doing correct. I've been using the remesh, I just need more practice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments you need a low poly mesh with a good topology for animation. If you have sculpted the head with dyntopo or the remesher then you can retopologize it to get the low-poly mesh.
Alternatively, you can use a low-poly base mesh and use sculpt tools to get the shape that you are after.

The mouth is created in a closed/relaxed position because the lips get stretched when it opens. The mouth consists of edge loops that form the lips. If you extrude these edge loops towards the inside of the head, you can easily create an oral cavity.

Teeth and tongue are separate meshes. You can make your own object from them.

[image: head with oral cavity]